# Updating a single file in a CPIO archive

Tags: disk-image, cpio

I have a CPIO archive with the Linux image on it. With `binwalk` I can see that there are the following chunks:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel", file name length: "0x00000007", file size: "0x00000000"
120           0x78            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
244           0xF4            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode", file name length: "0x00000015", file size: "0x00000000"
376           0x178           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc", file name length: "0x00000036", file size: "0x00000000"
540           0x21C           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin", file name length: "0x00000026", file size: "0x001A3800"
1718960       0x1A3AB0        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!", file name length: "0x0000000B", file size: "0x00000000"
1719296       0x1A3C00        gzip compressed data, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
32277012      0x1EC8214       Zlib compressed data, default compression
70217888      0x42F70A0       Unix path: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
85577309      0x519CE5D       MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 3
96044561      0x5B98611       Unix path: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
100702073     0x6009779       Zlib compressed data, default compression
106454594     0x6585E42       MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 7
110250207     0x69248DF       Unix path: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
115809787     0x6E71DFB       Unix path: /usr/local/go/src/runtime/runtime-gdb.py
```

I need to extract the the gzipped one:

```
1719296       0x1A3C00        gzip compressed data, NULL date (1970-01-01 00:00:00)
```

and replace a single binary file within it, then repack the image.

That gzipped content is another CPIO image.

What is the best/easiest way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer to this question is incomplete, since it only describes how to extract a single file from a cpio archive.

It appears to me that cpio archives cannot be modified in-place, so you would have to extract and then create a new one:

```
mkdir tmp && pushd tmp
cpio -idm < ../archive.cpio
find . | cpio -o > ../archive-new.cpio
popd && rm -Rf tmp
```

If you care about file ownership, you would probably want to run these commands as root.

Since you are using `binwalk` you might be interested in [the archive file format](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=formats-cpio-file-format) if you really want to make a surgical replacement without disturbing other entries.

This question probably would have been better on the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

the command you search for is

```
cpio -id 'TRAILER!!!' < archive.cpio
```

You may not need `-d` as file is located in to the root path
For more information you can check [this Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503934/how-to-extract-a-single-file-from-a-cpio-archive)